# How to export the text of <em> tags in sequence in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to parse the HTML file, which reads as follows:

```
<p class="title">
    <a href="#">#Who#</a>
    I don't <em>know</em>
    who you are
</p>
```

I want to extract all text that does not include 'a' tag in 'p' tag in the order.So what I expect is the result：

```
["I don't ", 'know', 'who you are']
```

I tried to use the following code：

```
>>>selector = Selector(text="<p class='title'><a href='#'>#Who#</a>I don't <em>know</em>who you are</p>")
>>>p_txt =selector.xpath('//p[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
["I don't ", 'who you are']
```

As a result, the text in 'em' tag is ignored.I also tried to use the following code：

```
>>>p_txt =selector.xpath('//p[@class="title"]/descendant::text()').extract()
['#Who#', "I don't ", 'know', 'who you are']
```

But it will also export the text in 'a' tag.Does anyone have a good solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to get all descendant text nodes of `p` *excluding* text nodes from `a`:

```
//p[@class="title"]//text()[not(parent::a)]
```

P.S. In case if link looks like `<a href="#">something <b>bold</b> inside</a>` you might need to replace `(parent::a)` with `(ancestor::a)`

Comment: Thanks for your help.I want to ask how to use `[not(parent::a)]`  in `normalize-space()` because my return is `["\n\t\t I don't ", 'know', 'who you are']`?

Comment: Try `p_txt = [node.strip() for node in selector.xpath('//p[@class="title"]//text()[not(parent::a)]').extract()]`

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much.